# Can the TensorFlow MTCNN model converted to the TensorFlow Lite format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert MTCNN model (https://github.com/blaueck/tf-mtcnn/blob/master/mtcnn.pb) from .pb file to .tflite and get problems with input and output shapes. Original input shape is ?x?x3 and output shape is Nx4 where N is number of detected faces.

I've tried to set the input shape to [None, None, 3] and get error *"None is only supported in the 1st dimension"*. Then I've set this to [500, 500, 3] and get other error *"Check failed: batch == 1 (500 vs. 1)"*. Then I've set the shape to [1, 500, 500, 3] and get *"ValueError: The shape of tensor 'input' cannot be changed from (?, ?, 3) to [1, 500, 500, 3]. Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 4"*.

UPD: I've converted original caffe model from input shape [None, None, 3] to [500, 500, 3] but this does not solve the problem.

I want to convert this model to .tflite format. Can I actually do this?

Answer (score -2):

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
tflite_model = converter.convert()


with open('8bit_quantized_model_in_.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

def representative_dataset():
    for i in range(<>):
      testimage = cv2.imread('path')
      yield [testimage.astype(np.float32)]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This will not worked as the input is a frozen graph while the API is used of `saved_model`.